# Writing playlists to iTunes in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios4, playlist

The Apple documentation on the MPMediaPlaylist class is pre-iOS4, so it definitively states that you cannot write new playlists to iTunes on the phone with the SDK. However, with the iOS4 update, users can create and save new playlists on the phone. Is this functionality offered to developers as well? If so, could someone point me to appropriate documentation?

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to find any indication that programmatic playlist creation is supported under iOS 4.